# hp envy x360 touchpad not recognized 20.04.1

Tags: mouse, touchpad, hp, touchscreen

I recently downloaded unbuntu linux on my machine it’s the newest version of the HP Envy x360 and it’s touchpad and touchscreen are not being recognized on any version of linux. By this I mean they don’t work at all and when using “xinput list” nothing that describes my touchpad or touchscreen shows up. I can provide more information but i have tried a couple of things.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You need a kernel version 5.8 or newer, it's got all the new cool drivers.
So you have two options:

## Update to Ubuntu 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10 comes with the 5.8 kernel. This option is preferred over manually upgrading the kernel, because 20.10 fully supports the 5.8 kernel and so should be more stable. Lucky for you, upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10 is easy.

1. Run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.
2. Run `do-release-upgrade`.
3. Follow the instructions on screen.
4. Make sure the update was successful with `lsb_release -a` or `neofetch`, and check the kernel version with `uname -r`.

## Upgrade kernel manually

1. Check your current kernel version with `uname -r`
2. Download the mainline Linux kernel of your choice [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). For 64bit architecture you'll need `linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb`, `linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb`, `linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb` and `linux-modules-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb`
3. Run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in the directory with the downloaded .deb files.
4. Reboot and check kernel with `uname -r`. Grub should automatically detect the new kernel version and boot it as default.

[Instructions from itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/)